# jQuery validate : accept one or two digits after dot

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I use this custom validator for money fields, it accepts $ sign, and dot or comma. But it's not perfect :

```
$.validator.addMethod("money", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.match(/^\$?(\d+(?:[\.\,]\d{2})?)\s?\$?$/);
}, Error money message ...");
```

The problem is :

122.22 $ is accepted and that's goot
122.2 $ is not accepted, but i want to accept one or two digits after the dot/comma

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace `\d{2}` with `\d{1,2}`:

```
^\$?(\d+(?:[\.\,]\d{1,2})?)\s?\$?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bW5oT7/1)

The `{n,m}` syntax means: between *n* and *m* times.